# excel IF formula question

Tags: excel, vba

i am building a formula like this:

```
=if(a1="something" or a1="alex","returned","not found")
```

but i guess the syntax is wrong. what is the correct way to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=if(or(a1="something",a1="alex"),"returned","not found")`